# What is the Font Awesome icon for "Language" selector?

Tags: localization, icons, font-awesome

I am using **[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)** in my entire site, now I want to give some visual feedback to the user, so he/she knows that "`this dropdown`" is a language selector.

I am not sure about of any of my selections, is there any standard? This is my list:

1. icon-globe
2. icon-flag
3. icon-compass

I am not interested in showing the active language, but I guess I must to :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per github [question](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/904), the language icon will be implemented in version 4.0. You can do a +1 for that request.

**Edit**

Language icon already added to the  latest version: see here http://fontawesome.io/icon/language/ .

Comment: Perfect answer can't ask for more... I did Google this, couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

The icon is already available in version 4.1

You can download it [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/language/)